# Как сохранить путь выбранного файла в проводнике?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qfiledialog, pyside6, getopenfilename

Я делаю приложение на *Python* с помощью *PyQt5* / *Pyside6*, в котором при нажатии кнопки, у меня должен открываться проводник, и в нем пользователь может выбрать нужный файл.

Мне не нужно его открывать, нужно просто получить путь выбранного файла.

Я нашел на *steckoverflow* команду для открытия проводника:

```
os.system(r"explorer.exe c:\\")
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я смогу получить сам путь выбранного в проводнике файла?

Comment: https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-file-dialog/

Comment: По идее у тебя должен где-то вызываться метод `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, ... )` - как-раз этот метод и возвращает полный путь к файлу.

Comment: @splash58 Нет, вы не поняли, приложение написано на Pyside 6, и имеет похожую структуру с PyQt, но команды все равно разные, так что это не подходит

Comment: @АндрейКоробейников Нет, не вызывается, я поискал

Answer (score 0):

> PySide — это проект создания привязки Qt к языку программирования Python. Он направлен на реализацию поддержки всех возможностей Qt, в том числе QtQuick и QtMobility.

То есть используются те же методы что и в PyQt.

```py
from PySide import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        ...

    def showDialog(self):

        fname, _ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file',
                    '/home')
        # fname - и есть путь к файлу
        
        f = open(fname, 'r')
        
        with f:
            data = f.read()
            self.textEdit.setText(data)
```

Данный пример показывает как открыть файл. [Здесь подробней.](https://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/dialogs/)

Comment: AttributeError: module 'PySide6.QtGui' has no attribute 'QFileDialog'    Это может быть из за того, что аргумент класса у меня QtWidgets.QWidget, а не QtGui.QMainWindow?

Answer (score 0):

> Класс **`QFileDialog`** предоставляет диалоговое окно, позволяющее пользователям выбирать файлы или каталоги.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QFileDialog.html#qfiledialog

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> static PySide6.QtWidgets.QFileDialog.**`getOpenFileName`**([parent=None[, caption=""[, dir=""[, filter=""[, selectedFilter=""[, options=QFileDialog.Options()]]]]]])¶
>
> Parameters
> parent – PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget
>
> caption – str
>
> dir – str
>
> filter – str
>
> selectedFilter – str
>
> options – Options
>
> Return type
> (fileName, selectedFilter)